# How to word wrap an echo description

Tags: php, word-wrap

Am i using wordwrap right? cause its not working. didn't know that simply echo does wrap text..

```
<p><?php echo wordwrap(ucfirst($row->description), 10);?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `wordwrap` inserts `ASCII` linebreaks (`\n`). When you want to visually display those linebreaks in HTML use the third parameter of `wordwrap` and specify `<br />`.

```
<p><?php echo wordwrap(ucfirst($row->description), 10, '<br />');?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read documentation on all native functions on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

In you case, you did not supply a third parameters so it defaults to "`\n`" (newline) which you will only see in your source code. You probably want "`<br />\n`" as your third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to truncate the description, you can use *mb_substr()*

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php